# How to find words by partially strings

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying to solve this problem for hours, but I dont know how to approach it, so I would need a push to a right direction.

I want to create a page where users can find the appropriate word, by providing word length and characters.

For example, user wants to find all the 5 letter words, where the second letter is R and fourth V, like this:

_R_V_

I have a table with column WORDS with words "letter", "moon", "drive", "mrive" and the query should return: "drive" and "mrive".

Is it possible to do it in MySQL?

While I was looking for the direction I found that I should create a trie structure. I dont know how to do that, but I will learn it if there is no easier way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`LIKE`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.word_col LIKE '_R_V_'
```

`_` Wildcard stands for any single character. This will also force the string to be 5 characters in length, since `%` wildcard is not used.

You can find a great explanation about `LIKE` wildcards in the link above.

Comment: Omg, i couldn't imagine it was that simple. I know I should not thank for answers, but thank you a lot for saving me time :) Great regards from Serbia

Comment: It's ok to thank for an answer by a comment, just not by an answer. No problem mate.